# Can't add to time?

Tags: php, date, date-time, timestamp

What's the best way to add to `time()`?

For example: `time() + 5` will return `5`, not the current unix timestamp with 5 added to it. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh you have to wrap in quotes.

```
(time() + 5)
```

Works. ***Sigh***